# Inference, effect of diet on performance

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, inference

I'm new to statistics and inference, now taking my first course. I'm having trouble in this exercise to even determine what I'm supposed to be looking at:

```
Five untrained persons are tested by having them run one kilometer. Then
they're put on a special diet for a week, at which point they're tested again.
Determine if the diet had any effect on performance by calculating a confidence
interval with confidence level 95%.
```

The data is (pre-, post-; in minutes) $(6.72, 6.55), (8.10, 7.78), (10.05, 8.40), (4.92, 5.20), (9.17, 9.15)$, but like I said my problem is really about what I'm supposed to do. I've done one other confidence interval exercise prior to this, it was about giving the confidence interval for the mean of a data set, it went fine but in this case I'm at a loss regarding what's supposed to be calculated.

Hints would be much appreciated.

(There's no key to this exercise. In another exercise regarding this same data, it is said "you may assume the variances are as in the previous exercise", i.e. the one above. I'm afraid that doesn't tell me anything.)

Comment: Have you considered asking your teaching assistant, community TA, user group, peers, or prof who assigned the question?

Comment: Sure, but I was foolish enough to believe I could do it on my own and so I won't be able to ask before it's due, so I turned to the internet. :)

Comment: Wouldn't want you to lose faith in the internet: Try calculating the confidence interval for each group (pre and post).  If the confidence intervals of the diets don't overlap, you'll have some evidence that the treatment had a significant effect.

Comment: The correct method should be 1) calculate 5 differences, 2) calculate the mean of the differences, and 3) get the confidence interval of the difference.